# Spark, Pyspark issue on Ubuntu

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to using spark and after installing it in my ubuntu system i am facing an issue.

I have downloaded the spark environment, mongo-hadoop connector, and i have java in my system after this if run PySpark(to get the shell) in the cmd line it shows cmd not found or if import the package pyspark_mongo in python it shows no such library.

If i try to run pyspark or spark submit in bin/spark it get an error: 
**Failed to find Spark jars directory (/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/jars).
You need to build Spark with the target "package" before running this program.**

I need this for data analysis can someone please advise what can be done.

Comment: Where did you get it ? I'm new too. I got `spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` from `spark.apache.org`, uncompressed to folder, and it this folder `./bin/pyspark` and `./bin/run-example SparkPi` work for me - Linux Mint (base on Ubuntu 14)

Comment: Furas these examples are provided for help in the directory.
I re-downloaded spark from the same source as yours so its working for me as well.
You can refer http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/quick-start.html for documentation on spark with different languages, helped me hope it helps you as well.